# How to get Site Owner Via Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, office365apis, graph-api

I'm attempting to get site owners via graph.

[Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_get#example) indicates this should be possible via /sites/{site-id} via `/sites/{site-id}`. I'm using beta.

The problem is I'm not even getting a blank owner attribute; I get everything else.

I'm curious if anyone has tried/confirmed this is working or not. I'm also curious if there is an alternate endpoint to retrieve owner info via graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I tried this before and by default Site resource does not provide `owner` property. As of now, by using `/sites/{site-id}` graph returns only below given properties:

1. @odata.context
2. createdDateTime
3. description
4. id
5. lastModifiedDateTime
6. name
7. webUrl
8. displayName
9. root
10. siteCollection

However `owner` property could be retrieved using `Site.Drive` property. To get the `owner` property, you need to expand and select the `drive` property while fetching site information like given below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}?$select=*,drive&$expand=drive
```

Comment: Thanks! that's helpful. I now get a owner & creator return, however, both values are blank

Comment: When I tried this I was getting the correct name of owner.

Comment: Both that, and `/{site-id}/drive/` appear to be pulling the default documents library and attempting to pull the owner of that.